# nodejs: Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 13, got 11 at bindings.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to use netroute module in my project. When I test it in test.js file and write `node test.js` everything works as expected. But when I try to load it into my big project I get this error:

```
{"stack":"Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 13, got 11.\n    at Module.load (module.js:352:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:308:12)\n    at Module.require (module.js:360:17)\n    at require (module.js:376:17)\n    at bindings (~/node_modules/netroute/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:74:15)\n    at Object.eval (~/node_modules/netroute/lib/netroute.js:3:19)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:452:26)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:470:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:352:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:308:12)"}
```

I tried running npm update, tried every possible release version of netroute and bindings.js, tried reinstalling all modules with no success.

I have not updated nodejs, and I have checked that there is only one version of npm and nodejs in apt-cache.

What can be the problem? Why does it works standalone and don't work in my project? I am using grunt in my project (starting with `grunt start`), can  the version be configured there or somewhere else?